# Traveling to a country known for mass surveillance. How can I protect my data/privacy?

Tags: usa, china, security, privacy

In the next year I will likely go to China, USA and a couple other countries. Both China and the US are known to sometimes take your electronics when arriving and searching them, possibly [even installing things on them](https://www.cnet.com/news/china-is-reportedly-scanning-tourists-phones-with-malware/).

[This](https://www.businessinsider.com/can-us-border-agents-search-your-phone-at-the-airport-2017-2?r=DE&IR=T?r=US&IR=T) is a good example of what I'm talking about.

Neither I nor my friends (to my knowledge) do anything shady or have extremist views (those views are luckily a rarity here in central/western european), but it's very possible that my friends or even I have said a (non threatening) thing or two about Hong Kong or Trump. With China there is a real risk that someone said something pro Hong Kong that they're not happy about which could deny me entry, while I would fear for my privacy in both cases.

I don't like to have my devices compromised and while I don't have any sensitive personal data in the traditional sense on them, they can have sensitive company data and are connected to my online presence. That means accounts, passwords, bank accounts, access to company data and accounts, basically everything.

How can I protect my (and my companies) data, information and privacy when I can not guarantee that my devices aren't compromised? I'm thinking burner phone and notebook, but if something is installed (e.g. government malware), that means that every login could be tracked, the account information taken and used against me.

It sounds a bit paranoid but unfortunately, reportedly this is already happening (see news articles in the beginning) and will only get worse.

Comment: You may find better answers at our sister site [security.se], where there are already a number of good questions and answers. For example [What are prudent security precautions to take for business travel by people with access to sensitive info?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/11612/11291)

Comment: Even without [GDPR](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/) it's questionable that company information is being stored on a personal device. Perhaps it's a company phone and you are going on a business trip.

Comment: Carry a travel device. Don't carry your main device.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only surefire way to avoid the possibility of your data being viewed in these countries is *don't carry data in any form*. The only surefire way to avoid the possibility of having your devices' OS augmented by governmental addition is *don't carry any devices*.

As the other answer notes, you can minimize the risk by carrying disposable devices with minimal, nonoffensive data. You can maintain your data solely in the cloud, but be careful not to carry software that will allow snoopers to identify those accounts, or worse, allow them access.

Answer (score 8):

One option would be to not have any devices with you.  Buy a cheap phone when you arrive in the country, use it in the country, and then discard it, sell it, give it away, or whatever before you go back home.  That way your primary device with personal and company information is not placed at risk.  Alternatively, buy a cheap device in your own country, and put a minimal clean social media profile on it so it won't seem suspicious.

Comment: Note that you can't safely log on to *any* of your accounts on this device...

Answer (score 3):

For this answer I'm assuming you are a normal traveler, who is concerned about their privacy. This means you'll want to take your own phone and devices, and you won't want to spend a lot of time and hassle on things like throwaway devices.

People who are under a specific threat, such as journalists or human rights activist, will have to take **much more stringent measures** which aren't covered here.

Also I'm not going to discuss things that you've published on the internet (e.g. tweets or facebook posts), or the case where the government in question can get the information directly from the servers (e.g. if Facebook gave them access). Those are "out there", and most impossible to retractively control.

### Why does it concern me?

As noted elsewhere, millions of people visit countries like the US, UK, China or Turkey without a hassle and without being systematically searched. However it *does* happen.

Furthermore, if it happens to you is **outside your control**. It is not like "you only get checked if you did something". Reasons for a digital check might include:

- You have the same name as someone on a watchlist
- An unfriendly neighbor reported you to the authorities
- You fit into a "profile" that makes you prone to checks (e.g. you are from a specific country, have a specific gender, age , non-white, you have bee to a "suspicious" country in the past, ...)
- You are ["randomly" selected for screening](https://onemileatatime.com/what-does-ssss-on-boarding-pass-mean/)

When people tell you "it never happens", it means just that it never happens *to people like them* (e.g. white, well-off tourists).

Also, don't be fooled that those searches are only about "terrorism" or violent crime. A young woman visiting extended family may have her WhatsApp searched just to check if she's taking an illegal Au-Pair job, for example.

### Am I fine if my device is "secure"?

Modern phones and computers are often "secure" in the sense that they are almost impossible to access without the proper password; at least not by a border guard.

**That makes no difference.**

If they want to search your device, the agent will simply ask you to unlock it. They are legally entitled to do so, and they can **refuse entry** if you don't. For a normal traveler this is actually worse than having someone look at their Facebook.

**The only solution is to not have the data on you when you cross the border.**

If you do plan to not allow access, though, you should disable all biometric login methods (face, fingerprint) while in transit.

### What could happen?

As an average tourist, if you *do* raise flags the most likely outcome would be that you are held and questioned and possibly refused entry and sent home. The [high-profile cases you see on the media](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/aug/19/david-miranda-interview-detention-heathrow) will either involve someone who is of particular interest (e.g. because they are activists) or who have ties to the country already, or both.

Of course worse things sometimes happen (and depend on the country in question), but at the border they are generally only interested if letting you in is going to be a problem. Countries don't usually want to cause incidents with random tourists for no particular reason.

At least that is true for most countries - you should still read your government's travel warnings.

General rules would include:

- Answer questions truthfully, but don't volunteer any information on your own
- Be friendly and cooperative (you are legit after all)
- If they ask you to unlock your device, do so (especially if you removed sensitive information beforehand)
- You can contact your embassy when you are accused of a crime; but they won't help you "get in"

### What can I do?

- Bring only the devices you actually need
- Delete all apps that have confidental content (e.g. social media apps, email, messaging apps)
- Remove your email and messages from the built-in apps
- Log out of all websites that have confidential content, and clear your browser cookies
- If you use a password manager (which you should), remove it from your device and keep the data in the cloud. 1Password, in particular, has a "travel mode", which wipes passwords from your devices when enabled, and restores them afterwards.

In general, only wipe things that you actually care about. If you show up with a "blank" device, that may also raise a flag.

You can then restore everything after you cleared immigration.
If you care about your photos, you could back them up to the cloud before crossing the border, and delete them from the device.

Especially in countries like China you should also **consider using a VPN**, which decreases the chance that the local ISP can intercept or block your connection.

Also, **travel without company data**. For company trips, [companies often have specific rules](https://basecamp.com/handbook/15-international-travel-guide) on what you can do with their data. You may even be liable if it gets exposed in such a situation and didn't follow company rules.

### Will they bug my phone?

For normal people: Most likely not. If you don't unlock it there is a chance that they may take it away to unlock it with specialized equipment.

Bugging your phone is work, and there is a risk that you discover how they did it and go public and figure out a way to prevent them. They won't do that for just the offchance that you might say something midly critical of their leader to your online friends.

Mass surveillance is usually done through other means than bugging people's phones at border posts.

However, *if* you are separated from your device at the border you can either:

- Trust that it is fine
- Factory reset the thing and hope that it is enough
- Treat it as compromised and throw it away
- Have it inspected by an expert for backdoors

While the chances are remote, it is ultimately your decision what to do.

### Caveat

In the end, you'll have to make up your own mind about what you want to do. The above is my personal understanding and analysis. As those cases are very, very rare it is almost impossible to find enough people with personal experiences to discover a pattern...

Comment: This is a better answer than the other one, but I still accept the other answer for now until a couple of things are addressed. What might the consequences be of raising flags due to a pretty much blank phone? Your answer ignores that stuff might have been installed by immigration, thus logging back in after immigration might still be an issue.

Comment: I added some lines on those questions, although I don't think it is very relevant to "normal" people...

Comment: I know several white people that are often selected for secondary screening. Your statement that "secondary screening never happens to white tourists" is obviously false.

Answer (score 2):

If I were sufficiently paranoid, …

I would assume the operating system itself is "safe."  For an iPad or IOS, I would backup to my laptop and reset to factory settings.  Then re-install only those apps I intend to use while traveling.  (If you suspect something unwanted has been installed, reset again.). I presume one can do something similar with Android or Windows Phone.

For the laptop, I would store my entire user account in a cloud account, delete the account, reinstall a clean O.S., and re-install the user account after arrival.  If this is not possible in China, it might be worthwhile to pack the account into a compressed and encrypted backup on an SD card, hide that in a digital camera, and hope they don't find it.

Generally, the SD card in a digital camera has a file system with specific directories the camera uses, and using the camera alone will not reveal those files exist.  Snoops wanting to check would have to remove the SD card and put it in a computer (or mount the camera via USB as a "disk").

Answer (score -5):

In my close to 30 years traveling to China and the US which you tagged I have never had a border agent or anyone else even touch my electronics much less take it away from me for even 1 second, on planes and going through security etc I always keep devices powered off anyway just to save battery but it also stops anyone remotely trying to install things since I don’t care how good of a hacker you are you ain’t that good that you can install on a turned off device.

Comment: Just because it didn't happen to you mean that its impossible. There are many instances as reported in the post.

Comment: Turning off doesn't always work. The border security can demand to turn on and can refuse entry if you refuse or something like that.

Comment: @AnishSheela yes and at the same time just cause it did happen to them doesn’t mean it will as reported as well, so what’s your point ?

Comment: @AnishSheela again I fail to see your point? Border security can just as well not believe you are a genuine tourist and deny you chess if you don’t bring any electrical devices, just cause you didn’t, this question will come down experiences, there is no right or wrong answer here

Comment: @Willeke my point is that nothing is, if they really want to check there is nothing you can do short of not traveling, if you accept traveling its the decent thing to do not to invite people to install things. At the end of the day its a “How long is a piece of string” question

Comment: It is quite simple to bring a new phone on which you only have installed the minimum of things, without connections to your private information on the phone or online, and reset that to factory settings if you think it has the extra software added.

Comment: @Willeke but thats my point, then you risk refusal if immigrations dont think you are e genuine tourist/business traveler, so then might as well not travel, all this hysteria is so blown up it becomes silly unless of course you work with company secrets or national security but then your devices are protected anyway

Comment: I know many people who still not use a smart phone or who have a smart phone that they use like the phones from before they were smart. And having to buy a new phone shortly before a travel is quite common as well.